# Atomics simulation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw atoms in this square where in the left of square blue atoms in the right of square red atoms and in the middle black.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\nuPi{3.1459265}
  \foreach \i in {11,10,...,0}{% This one doesn't matter
    \foreach \j in {5,4,...,0}{% This will crate a membrane
                               % with the front lipids visible
      % top layer
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the x coordinate
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the y coordinate,
                                     % gives a hight fill to the lipid
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the
                                      % molecule orientation      
      \shade[ball color=red] ({\i+\dx+\rot},{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=gray] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-0.9}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=gray] (\i+\dx-\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-1.8}) circle(0.45);
      % bottom layer
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{rand*0.1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{rand*0.1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{rand*0.1}
      \shade[ball color=gray] (\i+\dx+\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-2.8}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=gray] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-3.7}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=red] (\i+\dx-\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-4.6}) circle(0.45);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is not your code. If so, please attribute it correctly as a matter of courtesy to the original author (if nothing else).

Comment: I guess the original source is http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/membrane-surface/ Quote from there: "Proper attribution is to mention somewhere in your code or document who made the illustration and to provide a link to http://texample.net."

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you want to get,
[image]

If so, the most straightforward solution is to use the `ifthen` package, use it to define a command containing the color, and use this command to set the color in the several `\shade` commands.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\nuPi{3.1459265}
\foreach \i in {11,10,...,0}{% This one doesn't matter
  \ifthenelse{\i = 0 \OR \i = 11}{\newcommand{\colore}{red}}{\newcommand{\colore}{gray}}
\foreach \j in {5,4,...,0}{% This will crate a membrane
% with the front lipids visible
% top layer
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the x coordinate
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the y coordinate,
% gives a hight fill to the lipid
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the
% molecule orientation      
\shade[ball color=\colore] ({\i+\dx+\rot},{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)}) circle(0.45);
\shade[ball color=\colore] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-0.9}) circle(0.45);
\shade[ball color=\colore] (\i+\dx-\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-1.8}) circle(0.45);
% bottom layer
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{rand*0.1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{rand*0.1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{rand*0.1}
\shade[ball color=\colore] (\i+\dx+\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-2.8}) circle(0.45);
\shade[ball color=\colore] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-3.7}) circle(0.45);                                                               
\shade[ball color=\colore] (\i+\dx-\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-4.6}) circle(0.45);
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to load any additional packages as TikZ already allows you to set the colours conditionally as part of the `\foreach` loop. I'm not sure whether you want sudden, dramatic changes of colour like this:

[image: sudden]

or a gradual change like this:

[image: gradual]

Either way, here's the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\nuPi{3.1459265}
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using {\i == 11 ? "red" : (\i == 0 ? "blue" : "gray") }] in {11,10,...,0}{%
    \colorlet{mycolour}{\k}
    \foreach \j in {5,4,...,0}{% This will crate a membrane
      % with the front lipids visible
      % top layer
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the x coordinate
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the y coordinate,
      % gives a hight fill to the lipid
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the
      % molecule orientation
      % molecule orientation
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] ({\i+\dx+\rot},{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-0.9}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx-\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-1.8}) circle(0.45);
      % bottom layer
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{rand*0.1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{rand*0.1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{rand*0.1}
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx+\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-2.8}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-3.7}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx-\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-4.6}) circle(0.45);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\nuPi{3.1459265}
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using {\i > 0 ? "red" : (\i < 0 ? "blue" : "gray") }, evaluate=\i as \m using {abs(\i)*20}] in {-5,...,5}{%
    \colorlet{mycolour}{\k!\m!gray}
    \foreach \j in {5,4,...,0}{% This will crate a membrane
      % with the front lipids visible
      % top layer
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the x coordinate
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the y coordinate,
      % gives a hight fill to the lipid
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{rand*0.1}% A random variance in the
      % molecule orientation
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] ({\i+\dx+\rot},{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-0.9}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx-\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-1.8}) circle(0.45);
      % bottom layer
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dx}{rand*0.1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\dy}{rand*0.1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{rand*0.1}
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx+\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-2.8}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-3.7}) circle(0.45);
      \shade[ball color=mycolour] (\i+\dx-\rot,{0.5*\j+\dy+0.4*sin(\i*\nuPi*10)-4.6}) circle(0.45);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```